# how to render pptx,word in android

Tags: android

Does not the android webview support pptx,word mime types.Well the ios UIWebView does this and I was expecting the same.I searched the net,could not find any third party libraries for ppt,word,xls.Any word anybody?Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Does not the android webview support pptx,word mime types.

No. WebView renders Web content. PPTX and DOC are proprietary file formats from Microsoft that are not particularly related to the Web.

> Well the ios UIWebView does this and I was expecting the same

Perhaps Apple has a patent on rendering non-Web file formats in Web components.

> I searched the net,could not find any third party libraries for ppt,word,xls.

I sincerely doubt that there is a library (i.e., JAR) for this. There are apps that render (and edit) this content, and you can hand off your files to those apps easily enough using `ACTION_VIEW` `Intents` (with the right MIME type) and `startActivity()`.

Comment: yea..I was looking at quickoffice pro and documents to go..but still those need to be installed on the device rt..thats the problem.

Comment: @commonsWare:Is there any library(if available) please let me know. so that we can easily render msword and pdf in our app but not by using ACTION_VIEW Intents.thanks